# BSOD error 0xc0000001 after setup of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, laptop, bsod

I recently set up Windows 8.
The installation was successful but after restart I got a BSOD with error 0xc0000001.

A suggested solution is using the 'recovery options', but since I just set up Windows there's nothing to recover.

What can I do?

I don't have backup of my previous Windows 7.

Comment: Suggestions are here http://techmell.net/how-to/fix-error-code-0xc0000001-windows-8/ or here http://teamwindows8.com/2012/11/error-code-0xc0000001-in-winodws-8/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a problem with a driver. You can reboot the computer and press 'SHIFT+F8' in order to enter the recovery mode. From there you can have Windows 8 attempt to solve the problem automagically bu going to: Troubleshoot\Advanced\Windows Startup Settings\

From there you can select the reboot option and Windows 8 will attempt to solve the problem. If all goes well you should boot into the system without the error.